# CSS boxes going dont align on top

Tags: css

i'm having 3 containers with not the same height and i want to stack them horizontally howver the smaller boxes are at the bottom. How can i fix it?
[image]

Here is the code i'm using for the boxes:

```
.brand{
border: 1px solid black;
border-radius: 6px;
-webkit-border-radius: 6px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
padding: 9px;
margin-top: 10px;
background-image: url('/pcbuilds/assets/images/squared_metal.png');
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
display: inline-block;
width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the HTML code too? We can't really do much without it.

Comment: add vertical-align:top , else they stand on baseline and visually gets alignment to bottom

Comment: @GCyrillus it worked! Post it as an answer so i can vote :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vertical-align` has to be used for inline and inline-boxe content, defaut `vertical-align` value is `baseline`.:

```
.brand{
border: 1px solid black;
border-radius: 6px;
-webkit-border-radius: 6px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
padding: 9px;
margin-top: 10px;
background-image: url('/pcbuilds/assets/images/squared_metal.png');
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align:top;
width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just put

```
position:relative;
top:0px;
```